# My code was working well but after sometime firebase authentication is storing data well but relational database can't store uid and user information

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My code was working well before. After sometime firebase authentication is storing data well, but relational database can't store uid and user information.

```
String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(user_id);
current_user_db.setValue(email);
```

Comment: "relational database can't store uid and user information" Why not? What is the problem when you try to do this? Is there an error message?

Comment: There is no error message but there is no data stored as it was working earlier showing registered and logged in users